# Why does Google Plus often prevent me from "+1"ing an item?

Tags: google-plus-1

[image]

As shown in the picture above. After the "!" message, it goes back to a blank.

Comment: Do you have third-party cookies blocked? Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Nope. And yes. It works for some items, it doesn't work for others

Answer (score 2):

The exclamation mark means most likely the site was unavailable at one point in time.

> If the +1 button is unavailable or has stopped working, you'll see this image: [image]
>
> A +1 button error can occur for a variety of reasons, including the following:
>
> - Server timeout: Check your Internet connection and try refreshing the page.
> - Suspended profile: If your profile has been suspended, you won't be able to +1 content.
> - Apps user: If your administrator hasn't enabled Google+ for your domain, you won't be able to sign up for a Google+ account to use the +1 button.
> - Blocked cookies: If you've disabled 3rd party cookies in your browser you won't be able to use the +1 button.

From the [+1 button errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uis9t.gif) page.

Comment: Also: https://support.google.com/plus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&p=plusone_button_error&answer=1199142